# bash on command event (or shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Is there a way to capture all commands executed in a `bash` or even better in `sh`?

I need a wrapper script that gets called everytime a command is executed. Like when I type `cd /home/` I want my wrapper script `command_wrapper.sh` to be called. Inside I want to cancel the command or call another command.

```
#!/bin/sh
#command_wrapper.sh

echo "you tried to call the command [$@]"
```

It also would be okay if the script only gets called when a command doesn't exist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `DEBUG` trap to do this. In this trap, `$BASH_COMMAND` contains the command last executed.

```
trap 'echo "you tried to call the command [$BASH_COMMAND]"' DEBUG
```

Note that, if you are executing commands as part of your prompt or `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, the trap will run on these as well. You can add checks to see if `$BASH_COMMAND` is the same as `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to avoid some of these.

As for executing when the command doesn't exist, in bash, if a function named `command_not_found_handle` exists, that function is executed any time that a command is not found. It's executed with all of the arguments from the command line you tried to execute passed as arguments, so you can do something like this:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    echo "you tried to call the command [$@]"
}
```

This results in:

```
$ foo bar
you tried to call the command [foo bar]
$
```

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm! But do you know a way to interrupt a command which exists?

Comment: @MalteSchmitz I added some information about the `DEBUG` trap, which might help. :-)

Comment: wow! Thank you very much - that's exactly what I was searching for! :-D